# How to make ternary Plot 3D in a different situation?

Tags: plotting, graphics, inequalities

Owing to xzczd, I could make ternary plot with the following code:

```
r[AA_, BB_, CC_] := 4 Sin[AA/2] Sin[BB/2] Sin[CC/2];
old = {{0, 0}, {Pi, 0}, {0, Pi}};
begin = {{0, 0, 0}, {Pi, 0, 0}, {Pi/2, Sqrt[3] Pi/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
g[AA_, BB_, CC_] := 72 r[AA, BB, CC]^3;
p2 = Plot3D[g[x, y, Pi - x - y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + y < Pi], 
   PlotRange -> {0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Cyan]];
{error, ts} = FindGeometricTransform[Most /@ Most@begin, old];
newp2 = p2 /. 
   GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> 
   GraphicsComplex[Join[ts[{#, #2}], {#3}] & @@@ pts, rest];
mhs = Show[newp2, Axes -> {False, False, True}, Boxed -> False, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

The function: `g[AA, BB, CC] := 72(4 Sin[AA/2]Sin[BB/2]Sin[CC/2])^3 && AA + BB + CC = Pi.`

I am trying in vain to make ternary plot of the following minimum value function:
`R1[AA_,y_,z_]:=Sqrt[y^2+z^2+2y z Cos[AA]]/Sin[AA];
R2[BB_,z_,x_]:=Sqrt[z^2+x^2+2z x Cos[BB]]/Sin[BB];
R3[CC_,x_,y_]:=Sqrt[x^2+y^2+2x y Cos[CC]]/Sin[CC];` 
 `f[AA_,BB_,CC_,x_,y_,z_]:=R1[AA,y,z]^3+R2[BB,z,x]^3+R3[CC,x,y]^3+6R1[AA,y,z]R2[BB,z,x]R3[CC,x,y];
g[AA_,BB_,CC_]:= FindMinValue[{f[AA,BB,CC,x,y,z],x Sin[AA]+y Sin[BB]+z Sin[CC]==2 Sin[AA]Sin[BB]Sin[CC],-1<x<3,-1<y<3,-1<z<3},{{x,1},{y,1},{z,1}}]`;

The replacement of the former function by the latter function does not produce the result. How should I change the code to obtain its ternary 3D plot?

2019.6.5 I add ListPlot3D of my problem.[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "does not produce the result"? Does the code produce e.g. a blank plot or some warning, or the calculation never finishes?

Comment: The calculation did not finish. After 15 minutes, it was aborted. Should I continue the calculation more than 15 minutes? - seiichikiri

Comment: Does the color of your code become dark blue? If so, you're probably out of memory so the kernel crashes. (Notice `FindMinValue` is expensive, and, are you sure there exists a minimum when  `AA`, `BB` or `CC` tends to `0`? )

Comment: I computed the above 'f[AA_,BB_,CC_]' discretely.
    t1 = Table[f[0.1, i, Pi - 0.1 - i], {i, 0.1, 3.0, 0.1}]
    t2 = Table[f[0.2, i, Pi - 0.2 - i], {i, 0.1, 2.9, 0.1}]
    -----
    t30 = Table[f[3.0, i, Pi - 3.0 - i], {i, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1}]
Warnings of iterations and allowable ranges appear.
And made its triangular matrix.  By it I made 'ListPlot3D[Data]' as follows.
In order to compute with original code, can we control the number of computation or divide the area '0 < x < Pi, 0 < y < Pi, x+y < Pi' to several ones, compute them one by one and assemble them to a picture?

Comment: `RegionFunction` is also an option for `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: I posted the image of an inequality to ADGEOM. It is a combination of ListPlot3D and Plot 3D. Thank you very much. -https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/AdvancedPlaneGeometry/conversations/messages/5284